# Hierarchical Select List using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I have two select list,
**Select list 1** contains the Mobile phone brands names

```
<select name="mobile-phone" class="mobile-phone">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="Nokia">Nokia</option>
    <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
    <option value="HTC">HTC</option>
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
</select>
```

**Select list 2** contains the phone type like

```
<select name="mobile-model" class="mobile-model">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="Nokia--Lumia-520">Lumia 520</option>
    <option value="Nokia--Lumia-620">Lumia 620</option>
    <option value="Samsung--Galaxy-s3">Galaxy S3</option>
    <option value="Samsung--Galaxy-s4">Galaxy S4</option>
    <option value="HTC--hero">Hero</option>
    <option value="HTC--one">One</option>
    <option value="Apple--iphone4">iPhone 4</option>
    <option value="Apple--iphone5">iPhone 5</option>
</select>
```

My quest is I want to display **Select list 2** according to the value users select in **Select List 1**.

If a user selects ***Nokia*** in first selection, then only ***Lumia*** phones should be shown in second select list. Like so, for other phones.

When ***None*** is selected in **First select list**, then **second select list** should not show anything, but still visible without any option (like disabled button).

How can I accomplish this using jQuery?

The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yNL5/) I have made from above select list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
$("#sel2").prop("disabled", true);

$( "#sel1" ).change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
    $("#sel2").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#sel2 > option").hide();
    $("#sel2 > option[value*='" + value +"']").show();
});
```

Only I put to selects Id for do the selection by Jquery more easy. Before I disabled the control wating for any selection, and when the first select change only I keep the option that macth with `option[value*='" + value +"']"`.

[Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/RCBF6/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
/* select the select element whose name is "mobile-phone",
   assign an event-handler for the 'change' event:
*/
$('select[name="mobile-phone"]').change(function () {
    // get the relevant/selected brand-name:
    var brand = this.value;
    /* find the option elements inside of the select element with
       name="mobile-model", enable them all:
    */
    $('select[name="mobile-model"] option').prop('disabled', false)
    // show them all:
        .show()
    // filter the collection, to find only those whose value does not start with the brand-name:
        .filter(function () {
            return !(this.value.indexOf(brand) === 0);
        })
        // disable those elements:
        .prop('disabled', true)
        // hide them:
        .hide();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J2ds5/).

References:

- [Attribute-starts-with (`[attribute^="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin that handles this exact case very nicely: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained .

Answer (score -1):

You should consider having two MySQL tables: brand, model. The brand table would just be a list of brands with IDs. The model table would contain a brand column where you input those IDs.

Then you should do a JSON query for the brand selected, and return a select list accordingly.

By doing it this way, you'll have an in depth database that you can call and manipulate in numerous ways.

Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
$(".mobile-phone").on("change", function(){
  var brand = $(this).val();
  $("[data-brand]").hide();
  $("[data-brand="+brand+"]").show();
});
```

And do this:

```
<option data-brand="Nokia" value="...
```

Comment: If I had privilege to use **ID** then I'd not put such crazy values for option like `<option value="Nokia--Lumia-520">` to make the relation between two select list... BTW there is no MySQL or PHP involved, just plain HTML and Js

Comment: Then that is a travesty! See my edit for a jQuery alternative.